# Openstack compute service and novcn console are not working

Tags: service, openstack

i am using openstack packstack Train release, i created some instances and everything was working fine,Now when i try to access to the instances's console, i am getting this error message :

```
 unable to load console. please reload page or try again
```

i did a : `cat /etc/nova/nova.conf | grep novnc` i found that the correct port 6080 is in use and the correct ip address but when i go to check systemctl status

```
● openstack-nova-compute.service - OpenStack Nova Compute Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/openstack-nova-compute.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (start) since Sun 2021-05-09 01:07:39 CEST; 2min 7s ago
 Main PID: 26350 (nova-compute)
    Tasks: 1
   CGroup: /system.slice/openstack-nova-compute.service
           └─26350 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/nova-compute

May 09 01:07:39 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting OpenStack Nova Compute Server...
```

When i go to check the log file, i'm finding this error :

```
 ERROR nova MessageDeliveryFailure: Unable to connect to AMQP server on 10.53.193.171:5672 after inf tries: Queue.declare: (404) NOT_FOUND - failed to perform operation on queue 'reply_78acb3ad385641c6956a72bf3db5f041' in vhost '/' due to timeout
2021-05-09 00:45:41.162 20274 ERROR nova
```

Is there any help on how to solve this, please ?

Comment: I would troubleshoot the connectivity problem. Is the RabbitMQ server running at all? Is the IP address correct? If not, where does this address come from? Etc. Working with OpenStack requires more than basic networking skills. You will develop them fast.

Answer (score 0):

Solved !

I solved this by restarting the rabbitmq server :

```
# service rabbitmq-server stop
# service rabbitmq-server start
```